# Concatinate multiple file of different file shape throwing error :ValueError: Shape of passed values is (88, 57915), indices imply (88, 57906)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have multiple CSV files which I need to concatenate as the single data frame, in the end, I should have a DataFrame with 88 columns. The length of each 88 file different.

And so I tried the following python script,

```
file_names = []
data_frames = []
path = r'/path/*'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.tsv")) 
for filename in all_files:
    name = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(filename))
    file_names.append(name)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filename,header=None,sep='\t')[[7]]
    df.rename(columns={7: name}, inplace=True)
    data_frames.append(df)

combined = pd.concat(data_frames, axis=1)
```

Since the data file is of different length and the above script is throwing an error as follows,

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (88, 57915), indices imply (88, 57906)
```

I would like to know in this case how to concatenate multiple files of different size into a single data frame. Any suggestions would be great

Comment: pandas would have to put values on its own which it apparently can't do so either you lose information and delete rows for which you have partial information or put a default value in these rows missing columns (like 'n/a' or None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after long trail and error, I found a solution thankfully by using pivot tables.
The solution is,

> ## Starting with reading the dataframes,

```
data_frames = []
path = r'/home/user/projects/ballgown/*'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.tsv"))
```

> ### Adding the file name asa  extra column to the dataframe and make it as melted dataframe with three columns ['value','ID','Sample_name'],
>
> ```
> for filename in all_files:
> ```

```
    name = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(filename))
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filename,sep='\t')[['value']]
    #df.rename(columns={'FPKM': name}, inplace=True)
    df['Sample_name'] = name.replace('.bam.tsv','')
    data_frames.append(df.reset_index())
```

Then , I used pivot_table for reshaping it as I need, as following,

```
matrix = combined.pivot_table(index='Gene ID',columns='sample_name', values='FPKM')
```

here it prints the datafarme of 88 columns

Thanks for all suggestions..!!

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want concatenate on the columns by setting `axis=0`?

Comment: if I do axis=0 , then I get a  single data frame with all value as NaN, that why I tried with axis=1 , which helped when I do  df = pd.read_csv(filename,header=None,sep='\t')[[7]] instead of df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filename,header=None,sep='\t')[[7]] , but resulting datafarme will not give out the first column from each of those tsv files. The first column is common for all those *tsv files.

Comment: Does each dataframe have 88 columns? Try this code: `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df.values) for df in data_frames], axis=0)`

Comment: Each of those DATA frame has 8 columns and I need the 7th column for concatenating and that's why its,     df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filename,header=None,sep='\t')[[7]]